# Solving a system of equations using modular arithmetic modulo 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Give the solution to the following system of equations using modular arithmetic modulo 5:

> $4x + 3y = 0 \pmod{5}$
>   $2x + y \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$

I multiplied $2x + y \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ by $-2$, getting $-4x - 2y \equiv -6 \pmod{5}$.

$-6 \pmod{5} \equiv 4 \pmod 5$

Then I added the two equations:

> $4x + 3y \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$
>   $-4x - 2y \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$

This simplifies to $y \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$.

I then plug this into the first equation: $4x + 3(4) = 0 \pmod{5}$

Wrong work:

> Thus, $x = 3$.
>   But when I plug the values into the first equation, I get $2(3) + 4 \not\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$.
>   What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Revised work:

> $x = -3 \pmod{5} = 2 \pmod{5}$.
>   Now when I plug the values into the first equation, I get $2(2) + 4 \equiv 8 \pmod{5} \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign error on substitution, it should be $x\equiv -3\pmod{5}$.

You had $4x+(3)(4)\equiv 0$, that is, $4(x+3)\equiv 0$. From this we get $x+3\equiv 0$, so $x\equiv -3\pmod{4}$.

Negative numbers are sometimes troublesome, so we may wish to rewrite as $x\equiv 2\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction!

Comment: You are welcome. Once you have made a thousand more sign errors, you will be eligible to join my club.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a "cheats" method available here.  There are only $25$ possible values of $(x,y) \in (\mathbb{Z}_5)^2$.  We can just check them one-by-one, and see which ones work.

We could do this by hand, or on a computer.  In [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/):

```
for x in [0..4] do
  for y in [0..4] do
    if((4*x+3*y) mod 5=0 and (2*x+y) mod 5=3) then
      Print([x,y],"\n");
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

returns the single solution $(x,y)=(2,4)$.

Comment: +`Size(SymmetricGroup(IsPermGroup,1))` for using GAP. :-)

Comment: `Print(Concatenation([":",")"]),"\n");`

Comment: + `Number(Cartesian([0..4],[0..4]),t->((4*t[1]+3*t[2]) mod 5=0 and (2*t[1]+t[2]) mod 5=3));` :-)

Comment: One could also solve the system over $GF(5)$. First call `m:=[[4,3],[2,1]]; v:=[0,3]; e:=Z(5)^0;` and then `List(SolutionMat(TransposedMat(m)*e,v*e),Int);`

Answer (score 2):

You may consult Maple as follows to get that $(2,4)$ is the only solution for the system.

```
[> msolve({2*x+y = 3, 4*x+3*y = 0}, 5);

                                     {x=2,y=4}
```

Comment: You are becoming a "Maple Finatic" :-p (just teasing!) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Yes, I am :-)

Comment: @amWhy: I have the same one, Amy. :(

Comment: @amWhy: That is so kind of you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the last step, where you're solving for $x$.

$4x + 12 \equiv 0 \Rightarrow 4x\equiv 3 \Rightarrow x\equiv 2$.

Comment: Thank you! I've corrected my mistake.